# Visual C++ Error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

While the error is identical to what [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554070/error-c2143-syntax-error-missing-before-constant) have experienced, my surroundings are completely different. I actually do try to declare a constant:

```
const long CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x20000;
const long WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
```

The error is reported for the two constant names.

The constants declaration is located in a Header file, outside any class declaration.

Here is how the H file looks like:

```
#ifndef _ASD_SMARTWINDOW_MAIN_H_TAGXXXMAIH_
#define _ASD_SMARTWINDOW_MAIN_H_TAGXXXMAIH_

#include "ASDTail.h" //Queue support.

namespace ASDSmartWindowMaster
{
...
};

class ASDSmartWindowListener
{
};

const long CS_DROPSHADOW = 0x20000;
const long WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;

//Now comes a bunch of enums...
enum KLayeredWindowType
{ ... };


class ASDSmartWindow
{
};

#endif
```

Comment: You shouldn't use [reserved names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) for your include guards.

Comment: Meaning that I started the ifndef with _? Sorry, this is a 6 year old project I'm trying to resurrect, a lot of scary stuff in it ::- D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CS_DROPSHADOW and WS_EX_LAYERED are declared in WinUser.h. 
Verify that you didn't include it before your declarations.